# Android monkey test produced many activitiy instances which are in the INITIALIZING state

Tags: android, android-activity, monkey, initializing

After running monkey test for a long time, one activity in my application produced a large number of instances  which are in the **INITIALIZING** state. What could be the cause? How to solve this problem? This activity cannot be singleton.